# Divide a number n into two numbers such that sum of two numbers is n

Tags: java, recursion, partitioning

For example, if n is 4 then n1 + n2 = 4. n, n1, n2 >=0

the output should be

```
[4, 0] [0, 4] [1, 3] [2, 2] [3, 1]
```

I tried.

```
public static void partition(int n, int x, int y) throws Exception{
    int n1, n2;
    n1 = x; 
    n2 = y;
    System.out.println(n1 + " : " + n2);
    x = x - 1;
    y = y + 1;

    if ( x >= 0) {
        TestMethods.partition(n, x, y); 
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

I am calling the above method as TestMethods.partition(4, 4, 0);

I would like to see what improvements can I make to this method to make it more efficient.

Comment: Make it iterative instead of recursive

Comment: Looks good. Maybe remove the n1, n2 variables as they're just clutter, just use x and y.

Comment: Also the method depends on the user making sure that x > y. How about another entry-point method: public static void partition(int n) { partition(n, n, 0); } This simplifies using the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use recursion at all. Each recursive call will occupy extra space on the stack, which you really don't need. If `n` is large, this may result in a [`StackOverflowError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html). Of course this will depend upon your stack size. On my system, it threw the error for, *n = 9998*.

Just use a simple `for` loop. And you don't need those extra method parameters - `x` and `y`, IMO.

```
public static void partition(int n) {

    for (int i = n; i >= 0; --i) {
        System.out.printf("[%d, %d] ", i, n - i);
    }
}
```

And just use invoke it like - `TestMethods.partition(4);`

---

Note that you can save onto the number of iteration, by printing the symmetrical output in the same iteration. This will reduce the no of iteration to half:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= (n + 1) / 2; ++i) {
        System.out.printf("[%d, %d] [%d, %d] ", i, n - i, n - i, i);
    }
```

Comment: One could make use of the symmetry and print [x, y] and [y, x] and stop half way.

Comment: @Sylwester. Of course. If OP is ok with that output, then that can be reduced to half the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int num=4;
    for(int i=0;i<=num;i++){
        System.out.println("["+i+","+(num-i)+"]");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you **must** use recurtion then for example you won't need y parameter at all, because you can get it by subtracting x from n, y = n-x. And you could stop the recursion when x <= n-x, to not to have duplicate values like [3, 1] and [1, 3]

```
public static void partition(int n, int x) throws Exception{
int n1, n2;
n1 = x; n2 = n - x;
System.out.println(n1 + " : " + n2);
if ( n1 - 1 >= n2 + 1) {
TestMethods.partition(n, n1 - 1); 
} else {
    return;
}
}
```

Also this code can be simplified more, by removing the temporary vars n1, n2.